# 1ms posix timer is not timed correctly when debugging with GDB

Tags: c, linux, timer, gdb

I wrote a test program that created a 1ms posix timer, When running the program alone or debugging with GDB, the timing is accurate. Then I put the test program into my project code, when I run my project program, the timer is also accurate, but if I'm debugging my project with GDB, the timer is not timed correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CLOCKID CLOCK_REALTIME

timer_t timer_id;

int timer_thread_cnt = 0;
void timer_thread(union sigval v)
{
    timer_thread_cnt++;
    printf("timer thread count <%d>\n", timer_thread_cnt);
}

int start_timer(void)
{
    struct sigevent evp;
    int ret;

    memset(&evp, 0, sizeof(struct sigevent));
    evp.sigev_value.sival_int = 111; /* it can be passed into callback */
    evp.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD; /* The thread notifying way -- dispatch a new thread. */
    evp.sigev_notify_function = &timer_thread; /* The thread address */

    if (timer_create(CLOCKID, &evp, &timer_id) == 0) { /* create timer */
        struct itimerspec it;

        it.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        it.it_interval.tv_nsec = 1000000;
        it.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        it.it_value.tv_nsec = 1000000;

        printf("timer start...");
        if (timer_settime(timer_id, 0, &it, NULL) == -1) { /* if timer create success, start it */
            printf("start timer failed!\n");
            if (timer_delete(timer_id) == -1) {
                printf("timer delete failed!\n");
            }
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        printf("fail to timer_create");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    start_timer();
    while(1){
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

When the timer is not timed correctly, after the program runs for 10s, the value of the variable `timer_thread_cnt` in the program is about 2000. By the way, if the timing is 10ms, there will be no problem. Does anyone know what the possible cause of this problem is.

Comment: UPDATE: I replaced the posix timer with timerfd, now the timerfd timer`s 1ms timing is accurate during normal operation and debugging.